# Como aplicar css ao body dentro de um iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Quero aplicar background: transparent no body que é criado dentro de um iframe.

Por exemplo:

```
<iframe src="http://www.meusiteteste.com.br" id="frame_result_show" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Existe alguma forma?

Comment: Só por JavaScript.

Comment: Tem algum exemplo ai @bfavaretto ?

Comment: Acho que nem isso funciona, tem restrições de segurança se os domínios não baterem.

Answer (score 6):

Não é uma solução com CSS puro, mas veja se funciona pro seu caso específico.

Esta primeira parte na definição do `iframe` permite a transparência, mas nao a obriga.

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true">
```

e no source do `iframe` acrescenta-se no *CSS* a propriedade de transparência:

```
<body style="background:transparent">
```

Agora, se o conteúdo do `iframe` for de terceiros, creio que não haja um jeito "limpo" de fazer.